# is there a way or program to load a set of websites in IE 8 at the same time?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I open the same 20 sites daily from Favourites but I'm looking for a way to load all 10 or 20 sites sites with one or two clicks.  Currently, I have all of them in a folder and I choose "open in tab group" but the pages never load completely!  So, I have to click on each tab and press "Enter" in the URL bar to reload them completely which is annoying.

I'm looking for a simple program or way that loads sites properly.  Suggestions?

Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: I'd repeatedly press Ctrl-Tab, Ctrl-R

Comment: In what way?...

Comment: Ctrl-Tab selects the next tab, Ctrl-R reloads it

Answer (score 0):

[Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/) is a simple and customizable program that generally loads sites properly. Works well on your specified OS.

Comment: I don't like Opera.  I've got Chrome & Firefox but I still prefer IE because I don't like how sites look in them.

Answer (score 0):

I know AutoHotKey scipts can detect if a page has finished loading.  Perhaps, you want to check that out.

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic19256.html

The script will

> . . .navigate and wait until a webpage is completely loaded in an
>   Internet Explorer.